# Identify content change in client browser on server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, spring-security

I am storing some data in html field for display purpose. 
When I changed value of that field through inspect element, it get changed in server side also.

Due to project requirement, I am unable to use server side validation for such field.

Field with actual value:-

```
<input type = "text" name = "field1" id = "field1" value = "1234" readonly>
```

Value change after inspect element:-

```
<input type = "text" name = "field1" id = "field1" value = "56" readonly>
```

Disabling inspect element is not a good solution. I always want to get the actual value for those field on the server side.
If there is any change in the value, I am able to identify that the client has changed the data.
Please help me to solve this type of problem.

Comment: When I changed value of that field through inspect element, it get changed in server side also. How come that possible?

Comment: It will always be possible for the client to amend the DOM - it's a complete waste of time to try and stop that happening. It would be a better use of time to make your server code more robust, so that any values you expect to have a certain value are verified on the server.

Comment: I'd say you need some form of server-side validation for this to be bullet-proof.

Answer (score 0):

A readonly element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according form submits. 
a disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.

so you have to use 'disabled' instead of 'readonly'.
You can fetch value from server side directly if you want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting yourself into a situation where you would need to trust the clients. Typically DOM can always be modified and the content of the form you are sending can be tailored by the client and you cannot prevent that with plain HTML.

> If there is any change in the value, I am able to identify that the client has changed the data. Please help me to solve this type of problem.

In other words you want to authenticate those certain values you are sending to the server. Generally speaking you need to do the following:

- Identify the actors whom you trust to define those values (whether it's the client, destination server or some other component, etc...)
- Provide those actors a way to authenticate the values you don't want to be manipulated after they are defined. This will require a secret. You might want to take a look at digital signatures for example.
- Build a mechanism to verify the authenticity of those values at the destination. For example, have your server to verify the signature of the data values coming from the browser.

If the actor who is defining those values is your destination server (same actor as the verifier) and those values are security critical, there should be no reason to send them to the client in the first place - or if read access is fine, at least not having client to send the values back to the server.

The message authentication comes into the picture if your source and destination are different actors and you need to build a trust relationship between them.

Anyway a solution for your problem goes way beyond HTML or client-side JavaScript.